# How to get output with unique values but only with last instance of a duplicate key - unique_by

Tags: json, jq

I am currently working with jq to parse through some json. I would like to retrieve unique values based on a certain key. I came across `unique_by`. It does just that of getting unique values for key `name` but I am still not getting my desired output. From my understanding, `unique_by` looks at key `name` value an uses the first instance and then removes the duplicates that follow in the final output. However, I would like to grab the last duplicate key `name` value and display that in the final output.

Below is an example of my desired output. Is it possible to do this with `unique_by` or what would be the best approach?

`cat file.json`

Original json:

```
[
    {
      "name": "app-fastly",
      "tag": "20210825-95-448f024",
      "image": "docker.io/repoxy/app-fastly:20210825-95-448f024"
    },
    {
      "name": "app-lovely",
      "tag": "20211004-2101-b6a256c",
      "image": "ghcr.io/repox/app-lovely:20211004-2101-b6a256c"
    },
    {
      "name": "app-lovely",
      "tag": "20211007-6622-b3fooba",
      "image": "ghcr.io/repoxy/app-lovely:20211007-6622-b3fooba"
    },
    {
      "name": "app-dogwood",
      "tag": "20210325-36-2a349e9",
      "image": "docker.io/repoxy/app-dogwood:20210325-36-2a349e9"
    }
]
```

Jq Command:

```
cat file.json | jq 'unique_by( {name} )'
```

Current Output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "app-dogwood",
    "tag": "20210325-36-2a349e9",
    "image": "docker.io/repoxy/app-dogwood:20210325-36-2a349e9"
  },
  {
    "name": "app-fastly",
    "tag": "20210825-95-448f024",
    "image": "docker.io/repoxy/app-fastly:20210825-95-448f024"
  },
  {
    "name": "app-lovely",
    "tag": "20211004-2101-b6a256c",
    "image": "ghcr.io/repox/app-lovely:20211004-2101-b6a256c"
  }
]
```

Desired Output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "app-dogwood",
    "tag": "20210325-36-2a349e9",
    "image": "docker.io/repoxy/app-dogwood:20210325-36-2a349e9"
  },
  {
    "name": "app-fastly",
    "tag": "20210825-95-448f024",
    "image": "docker.io/repoxy/app-fastly:20210825-95-448f024"
  },
  {
    "name": "app-lovely",
    "tag": "20211007-6622-b3fooba",
    "image": "ghcr.io/repoxy/app-lovely:20211007-6622-b3fooba"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the last unique item, simply `reverse` the array first

```
jq 'reverse | unique_by( {name} )'
```

And if you want to retain the original order, `reverse` back again afterwards

```
jq 'reverse | unique_by( {name} ) | reverse'
```

Comment: Using `unique_by( .name )` would be better, if only for efficiency.